# NLTK POS Tags - Unable to Export CSV

Tags: python, twitter, nltk

I have this code which I have been using for sometime. I wonder if there is a way to read csv file per line (twitter feeds) and export the output in csv.

I am ideally looking to extract Noun terms per line i.e. in my case a twitter feed.

Here is the code. I am sorry but I am new to Python.

```html
import nltk
essays = u"""text here"""
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(essays)
tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
nouns = [word for word,pos in tagged \
 if (pos == 'NN' or pos == 'NNP' or pos == 'NNS' or pos == 'NNPS')]
downcased = [x.lower() for x in nouns]
joined = " ".join(downcased).encode('utf-8')
into_string = str(nouns)

output = open("output.txt", "w")
output.write(joined)
output.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

(csv docs) https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

```
import csv
all_nouns = []
with open('twitter_feed.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
     tweetreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
     for tweet in tweetreader:
        tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(essays)
        tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
        nouns = [word for word,pos in tagged \
            if (pos == 'NN' or pos == 'NNP' or pos == 'NNS' or pos == 'NNPS')]
        downcased = [x.lower() for x in nouns]
        joined = ",".join(downcased).encode('utf-8')
        all_nouns.append(joined)
csv_file = csv.writer("nouns.csv")
csv_file.writerows(all_nouns)
```

I'm afraid I don't have Python on my machine at the moment to test this but I have basically used the Python docs and your code to zip that script together, which should get you into the right direction to achieve what you want. If you need any more help or if I've misunderstood please let me know.